# Condition on join not working properly

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables

```
customers (id, name....,created_at)
coupons (id, customer_id, ....,created_id)
```

I am trying to get count of all those coupons where created_at is 2015-12-29 and where customer's created_at is not 2015-12-29

```
select 
    count(*) as aggregate 
from 
    `coupons` 
where  
    (select count(*) from `customers` 
    where 
        `coupons`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` 
    and 
        DATE(`customers`.`created_at`) <> '2015-12-29') >= 1 
and 
    DATE(`updated_at`) = '2015-12-29'
```

This query works fine, but when I add one more constraint to query `client_id = 1`, it doesnot work.

```
select 
    count(*) as aggregate 
from 
    `coupons` 
where  
    (select count(*) from `customers` 
    where 
        `coupons`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` 
    and 
        DATE(`customers`.`created_at`) <> '2015-12-29') >= 1 
and 
    DATE(`updated_at`) = '2015-12-29'
and
    `client_id` = 1
```

It should return non zero value, but it returns 0

Dummy data

customers

```
id, name,   created_at
1   ehsan   2015-12-29 12:10:10
2   ehs     2015-12-28 12:10:10
```

coupons

```
id, customer_id, updated_at            client_id
1   1            2015-12-29 12:10:10   1
2   2            2015-12-29 12:10:10   1
3   2            2015-12-29 12:10:10   1
```

Comment: Are the `created_at` columns stored as date types or a string?

Comment: There's no `updated_at` column in the `coupons` table.

Comment: It returns `2` for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0605/1

Comment: I had missed a part of query. Please recheck with updated question. Thanks

Comment: Still returns 2: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d080e/2

Comment: BTW, there are better ways to write it, either using `JOIN` or `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ...)`